# Why does an anonymous class constructed throw an error given named parameters in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm studying Groovy at the moment, and I have a question related to unexpected behavior when using anonymous classes.

So, I've learned that Groovy autogenerates smart constructors that can destructure the provided hashmap and set the given values to the corresponding properties:

```
class Greeter {
  String name
}

def alice = new Greeter(name: "Alice")
println "Hello, $alice.name" // "Hello, Alice"
```

Also, I've learned that it is possible to create derived classes anonymously like shown below:

```
def bob = new Greeter() {
  def greet() {
    println "Hello, $name"
  }
}

bob.name = "Bob"
bob.greet() // "Hello, Bob"
```

However, what I can't comprehend is what exactly is wrong with this scenario:

```
def chuck = new Greeter(name: "Chuck") {
  def greet() {
    println "Hello, $name"
  }
}

chuck.greet(); /*
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: Greeter(LinkedHashMap)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: Greeter(LinkedHashMap)
    at anonymous-class$2.<init>(anonymous-class.groovy)
    at anonymous-class.run(anonymous-class.groovy:17)
*/
```

So, here I basically combine the first and the second feature, and something breaks behind the curtains. Is that a known behavior or a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new Greeter(name: "Alice")`, it is first creating a new `Greeter` object using the default (zero argument) constructor, then assigning the property. You can *actually* generate the map inputs constructor using the `@Canonical` annotation:

```
@Canonical
class Greeter {
    String name
}
```

Now when you use the syntax from the question, it will work as expected, because you are calling an actual constructor.

Comment: Let's revise the stated: "The Greeter class does not have a generated constructor by default.".  Well, `groovyConsole` says otherwise:

```groovy
public class Greeter extends java.lang.Object implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject { 
    private java.lang.String name 
    // ...
    @groovy.transform.Generated
    public Greeter() {
        metaClass = /*BytecodeExpression*/
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: > Now when you use the syntax from the question, it will work as expected... Unfortunately, I see something else:  `Hello, Alice ; Hello, Bob ; Hello, {name=Chuck}`.  Perhaps, it casts LinkedHashMap to string. So I can't say the behavior becomes equivalent. Actually, this is indeed very curious, how Groovy auto-sets the properties behind the curtains - I can't see that happening outside of a constructor call, by the way, so it has to be implemented inside the default constructor (or `groovyConsole` AST analysis is lying and conceals the property assignments indeed).